# Create C#/WPF Button using a Wingding or Webding font Character

Tags: c#, wpf

Should be possible to create a button using a Wingding Chracter in WPF?  But, doesn't seem like "&xCB;" works to insert character 0xCB into the button Content.

```
 <Button 
    Name="Btn1"     
    Content="&xCB;"   
    FontFamily="Wingdings" />
```

[image]

Comment: Is a webding unicode?  I only see 8-bits...

Comment: `Content="&#xCB;"`